# Google Maps Android API issue with markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am going crazy! I add some markers and I save the id's of that markers in an Array. Later, I am using `getInfoWindow(Marker marker)` from my custom implementation of `InfoWindowAdapter` but the Marker in the parameter is not in the list I saved! Does the API copy the marker to pass it to `getInfoWindow`? How can I know which marker is?

Comment: The ids should be the same values unless there is a bug in Google Maps Android API v2 or (more likely) in your code. It is not possible to tell where is the bug unless you post some code. If you believe this is a bug in GMAv2, I will be glad to help pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the API copy the marker to pass it to getInfoWindow?

Yes. More specifically, `Marker` instances are not retained by the library. They are used solely for IPC over to the Play Services Framework app and back again. Hence, the `Marker` that you get back is a copy of the `Marker` that you created.

> How can I know which marker is?

Option #1: Use the `snippet` portion of the `Marker` to hold some identifier that you can map back to your data model, such as a key to a `HashMap`

Option #2: Use a library that does something akin to Option #1 for you, such as [Android Map Extensions](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions)

Comment: Thanks so much. It works, I will use snippet. Actually, I am currently using a HashMap.

Comment: @DídacPérez: FWIW, here is a sample project demonstrating Option #1: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Models